# how to use hive regexp_replace to replace space and all special characters with 'hyphen'

Tags: regex, replace, hive

I have a string like 'Strong-Memorial/123, Hospital | URMC' , how could I make it
'strong-memorial-123-hospital-urmc' using regexp_replace ? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`regexp_replace(columnName, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '-')`

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]` -> `^` placed in `[]` negates the match of alphanumeric (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) characters.
`+` sign -> matches 1 or more (if continuous special chars, will count as 1 match so only one hypen will be added to replace the whole match).